# Geoloqi Android SDK : How to listen to location changes for all members in a group?

Tags: android, location, listener

I am currently working with Geoloqi Android SDK on displaying the rough location of all the members in a particular group. I have successfully called for group/create and added anonymous users to the group. I have ran group/members that shows correctly the number of members i have in my group. The problem I have right now is figuring out how to listen to the location changes of all these members in the group. I have tried the group/locations api call but the location part of the JSON object is empty (I assume when anon users are added to the group they automatically broadcast their location updates). What are some other ways to listen to the location changes of all the members?